# Django: How to save data to ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a question concerning the following model. I want to populate the `ManyToManyField` from views.py instead of doing it from the Admin.

But how do I add data to the `genres` field which is the `ManyToManyField`?

**views.py**

```
content = Movie_Info(id = m_id,
                    title = data[0].get('title'),
                    overview = data[0].get('overview'),
                    release_date = data[0].get('release_date'),
                )
content.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Movie_Info_genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Movie_Info(models.Model):
    id             = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title          = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    overview       = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    release_date   = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    genres         = models.ManyToManyField(Movie_Info_genre)
```

Comment: Unrelated style advice: in Python/Django, it's strongly favored to name classes `MovieInfo` or `MovieInfoGenre` (or just `MovieGenre` or even `Genre`) rather than using underscores there. Also, this is probably an SO formatting problem, but you have a ridiculous amount of indentation when making `content`. :)  Plus, `release_date` should maybe be a `DateField`.

Comment: @Dougal, thanks for the advices. Regarding the indentation I'm using a plugin which does that for me ;)

Comment: Plus, there is no need for special "id" field in model. Django does it automatically for you.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use the [add method for related fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add):

```
# using Model.object.create is a shortcut to instantiating, then calling save()
myMoveInfo = Movie_Info.objects.create(title='foo', overview='bar')
myMovieGenre = Movie_Info_genre.objects.create(genre='horror')
myMovieInfo.genres.add(myMoveGenre)
```

Unlike modifying other fields, both models must exist in the database prior to doing this, so you must call `save` before adding the many-to-many relationship. Since add immediately affects the database, you do not need to save afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I had a further question to this also. Genre is supposed to be unique. With the following code it will raise error if the same genre is added twice. So I wonder, should I catch that error and do something about it. Or is there some better way to sort this problem out?

Comment: Use [Model.object.get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead.

Comment: "add immediately affects the database" is the very answer I'm looking for, thanks