# When I add() to a ManyToMany relationship, does it replace the previous records?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I'm creating a set of view for an app that adds and edits teams and volunteers. Volunteers can take part of as many teams as they wish, and a few of them are set as team leaders. Due to the need for flexibility of the process (I guess), I've left both items as separated (I'm open to suggestions on this, though!) and I'm trying to set consistency on the views. For example, I want to make sure that every time I add a team leader on one view, they are also enrolled as a team member.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    leaders = models.ManyToManyField(Volunteer, related_name='leaders', blank=True)
    enrolled = models.ManyToManyField(Volunteer, related_name='enrolled', blank=True)

class Volunteer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have a view on which I'm doing just this. After saving the form, I take each of the `leaders` and add them to the `enrolled` field. However, when I add them, I find that the previous values of enrolled on the field has been replaced by the new values I added. I could just save the previous values in a variable and reapply, but is it supposed to work this way?

```
class TeamUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
form_class = TeamCreateForm
model = Team
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    for i in self.object.leaders.all():
        self.object.enrolled.add(i)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('single', args=(self.object.id,)))
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Edit: adding the form and template. The former shows all the actual fields in the model (I had reduced them in order to simplify it for you, but I can post it all if you prefer).

```
class TeamCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        template_name = 'team_form.html'
        fields = '__all__'
```

Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Add or edit team{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="blue-text">add or edit team</h1>
    <form class="registration" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="white row z-depth-1">
          <small class="red-text">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</small>
          <div class="col s9">
            <label for="id_name">Team Name</label>{{ form.team_name }}
            <small class="error brick-text">{{ form.team_name.errors }}</small>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12">
            <label for="id_name">Team Leaders</label>{{ form.leaders }}
            <small class="error brick-text">{{ form.leaders.errors }}</small>
          </div>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue" onClick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Save</a>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Adding should not replace the existing relations. How are you checking the values of enrolled?

Comment: Can you show `TeamCreateForm`?

Comment: @knbk It's added. You can see it's a pretty standard ModelForm.

Comment: And your template? I suspect that the `enrolled` field is not submitted, so when the form is saved it'll clear the relation before you're adding any objects.

Comment: @arjun27 what you see is what it is. I'm very confused too. I add volunteers in another view altogether through an autocomplete Ajax field through and ´update´ field. Could it be perhaps that I get database problems since I use ´update´ in one and ´add()´ in another case?

Comment: I would doublecheck the behavior of `form.save()` here, you're not excluding `enrolled` from the form fields so if it's empty I'd expect that method to clear to m2m before you start adding the leaders.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper If I don't use save, I'm unable to use add(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366045/django-how-to-save-data-to-manytomanyfield

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure the instance exists in the database before adding new information to it. But if your form says that the new value of `enrolled` is the empty set, that will be saved along with everything else. Explicitly specifying the fields you want your form to include should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML form does not include `enrolled` field, but your ModelForm does include it. Since the ModelForm does not receive any data in the `enrolled` field, it'll assume that you explicitly removed all selected volunteers and remove them.

You need to explicitly define which fields are in your ModelForm:

```
class TeamCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        template_name = 'team_form.html'
        fields = ['team_name', 'leaders']
```

It is recommended to always explicitly name the fields instead of using `__all__`. If you don't and you add a field that shouldn't be edited by users, it can become a security issue.

Comment: You have spoken truth. This was the issue. Thank you very much!