# how to save many to many field in django

Tags: django

**I am trying to save students from addstudent form but it is not saving students and it is displaying error message 'error in form'.Is there any solutions for this code.I think the error is in html template.**
Error is like this:
AttributeError at /students/add/student/
'ErrorDict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/add/student/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'ErrorDict' object has no attribute 'status_code'

> models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    basic_price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    advanced_price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    basic_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    advanced_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Students',blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateField()
```

> forms.py

```
class AddStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

> views.py

```
def addstudent(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddStudentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save()
            student.save()
            messages.success(request,'student saved.')
            return redirect('students:add_student')
      #  else:
           # return HttpResponse(form.errors) --> it returns course

    else:
        form = AddStudentForm()
    return render(request,'students/add_student.html',{'form':form,'courses':courses})
```

> add_student.html

```
<form action="{% url 'students:add_student' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Full Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Course <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="course" id="select" required class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Select Your Course</option>
                                {% for course in courses %}
                                <option value="{{course.title}}">{{course.title}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Address<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Phone Number <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" data-validation-match-match="password" class="form-control" required> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="email" name="email" data-validation-match-match="password" class="form-control" required> </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="date" name="joined_date" data-validation-match-match="password" class="form-control" required> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Image <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" > </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-xs-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366045/django-how-to-save-data-to-manytomanyfield

Comment: that didn't helped me

Comment: Try to output `form.errors` instead. It will show where the issue is. Plus using `fields='__all__'` is not recommended, rather create a list of fields you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i have updated my questions now. please check it out .

Answer (score 2):

You should output the value of `form.errors` as suggested in the comments to discover the exact error. However, I can see two immediate issues that are likely causing form validation to fail.

Firstly, because your form contains an image upload you must set the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` in the template:

```
<form action="{% url 'students:add_student' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Second, the uploaded image exists in `request.FILES` so you need to pass that to the form:

```
form = AddStudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.Now i have updated my question and errors.Please check this out

Comment: You can't return `form.errors` from the view. You should remove the whole `else` block from the `form.is_valid()` test.

Comment: i think the error is while saving the course.I used HttpResponse(form.errors) and it printed out course

Comment: Once I used course as a CharField in models.py and it saved the data without any error but after i changed to ManytoManyField and migrate then it is giving me error

Comment: i removed the else block now its neither throwing any error nor saving the data

Answer (score 0):

You have to save many to many field after save method.

```
if form.is_valid():
        student = form.save(commit=False)
        student.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```